# How to use control ribbon retry in method level?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

I configured ribbon as show below:

```
ribbon.retry.enabled=true
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=15000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=15000
ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=2
ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=1
ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval=5000
ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=true
```

This is the global configuration, as far I know. The lease control in ribbon is in the service, you can change the ribbon configration as shown below either:

```
you-service.ribbon.retry.enabled=true
you-service.ribbon.ConnectTimeout=15000
you-service.ribbon.ReadTimeout=15000
you-service.ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=2
you-service.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=1
you-service.ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval=5000
you-service.ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=true
```

**The issue is: How to configure method to use ribbon retry or not ?**

Is there a way like : `you-service.you-method.ribbon.xxx`?

Comment: It's either all or just GET

Answer (score 0):

you can implements RetryListener and override  bool open() method.

```
 LoadBalancedRetryContext balancedRetryContext = (LoadBalancedRetryContext) context;
ServiceInstance serviceInstance = balancedRetryContext.getServiceInstance();

  System.out.println(serviceInstance.getServiceId());
        System.out.println(serviceInstance.getUri());
        System.out.println(balancedRetryContext.getRequest());
      
  if (url.contains("your url")){
            return true;
        }
```